# Conditional value in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form, in which I can set various client fields like client name client address and more.
Only the client name is a must field, and all the other fields can be empty.
After saving the client data I display to the end user the clients details page (with all the clients information).
 Now if the address field is empty I want to display some customized text for example "The Address is not set".
Currently my "show" page display only this

Address <%=h @client.address  %>

So if the address is empty I see nothing.
Can any one tell me how I can add this conditional text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways, here's a somewhat messy one

```
<%=h (@client.address.blank? ? "The Address is not set" : @client.address) %>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<%=h @client.address.present? && @client.address || "The Address is not set"%>
```

If you're using it often enough, you may consider making this a helper.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. The input remains empty

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that blank values are stored as "" and not `nil`.

Comment: Instead of !@client.address.blank? you can use @client.address.present? which is a little more readable.

Comment: Beerlington: I was not aware of that. Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this…

```
<%- if @client.address.blank? %>
  "The Address is not set"
<%- else %>
  <%=h @client.address %>
<%- end %>
```